# PHP AES Decode Method does not return any value

Tags: php, aes, decode

I have been trying to implement decode of certain number from SF to PHP.
i have to use AES method with vector and so i tried below code, but none of code has been return with decoded value and returning blank.

```
  $key = 'some key';
  $encyptedData = 'some encrypted data';
  $cipher="AES-128-CBC"
  $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
  $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);

  $original_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($encyptedData, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
```

I have tried multiple cipher methods but none of them is working, can some one guide me what is wrong in my code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are generating a new ("fresh") init vector (iv) on decrypting side, you need to use the iv that was used for encryption.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelFehr for replay, earlier i have tried whatever vector value i have received, but is also return same result, value is something like AA=

Comment: An IV for AES is always 16 bytes long, not less, not longer.

Comment: should i need to encrypt /decrypt or encode/code  it before use?

Comment: "*should i need to encrypt /decrypt or encode/code it before use*" - as encryption/decryption runs on binary data, the decryption method needs decoded data. At the moment, your question can't get answered because of missing a lot of information, so kindly edit your question and append some sample data, plaintext, ciphertext, key, iv and AES mode (CBC/GCM/CFB/OFB/CTR ?) - all of them use an IV.